# What is Deutsche Bank "Free Order"?

Tags: canada, money-transfer, international-transfer, european-union, wire-transfer

Want to transfer Canadian dollars to German DB bank in without converting to Euro.
Idea is to wait with the exchange till the time when exchange rate is more favorable to Canadian dollars. I was told by Deutsche Bank representative that I can create another account in foreign currency (Canadian) via Free Order.

I wasn't able to find anything remotely similar to "Free order" through my online banking interface and I'm hesitant to pester DB representative before I necessarily have to.
Is anyone familiar with the term "Free Order" and/or can provide any advice in that direction ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Free order most likely refers to the fact that they will place an order of foreign currency for free, when normally you would have to pay a fee to get foreign currency. You shouldn't worry about pestering DB representatives, that's their job.

Comment: Thanks MIchael
An in this scenario I would than (once the foreign currency account is set) just wire money from Canadian bank to German bank, right?

Comment: You can definitely wire money through assuming both banks can do that. You might have to pay a transfer fee though.

Comment: Thanks, any wiring service you would recommend ?

Comment: Your bank should offer wiring services.